# Fragments. Новое Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent

Допустим по нажатию на кнопку у меня открывается новое активити.

```
public void startSearch(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChoiceActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Это активити представляет собой следующий вид:

```
<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Во ViewPager добавляются Fragment, код адаптера ниже

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "1");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "2");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(),"3");
    adapter.addFragment(new FourthFragment(),"4");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
        public void addFragment (Fragment fragment, String Title){
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(Title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
}
```

Суть проблемы: Открывается новое Activity, но оно пустое. Не формируется корректно. Возможно кто-то сможет подсказать в чем загвоздка.

Comment: Код активити покажите

Comment: У вас в разметке еще проблема. Замените LinearLayout на CoordinatorLayout и добавьте во ViewPager `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`